# With Numpy how to turn a given 3D array into an array of 3x3 matrices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm learning Numpy at the Moment and I'm trying to wrap my head around Reshaping.
I have a 3D-Array that looks like this (values are random but the shape is important):

```
[[[37. 56. 56. 54. 82. 85. 68. 46.  6.]]

[[96. 20. 53. 52. 79. 94. 59. 29. 40.]]

[[57. 59. 38. 53. 88. 96. 61. 62. 48.]]

[[32. 92. 56. 52. 74. 12. 63. 58. 81.]]

[[16. 89. 24. 26. 33. 82. 80. 66. 89.]]]
```

and I want to turn it into an array of 3x3 Matrices like that:

```
[[[37. 56. 56.]
  [54. 82. 85.]
  [68. 46.  6.]]

 [[96. 20. 53.]
  [52. 79. 94.]
  [59. 29. 40.]]

 [[57. 59. 38.]
  [53. 88. 96.]
  [61. 62. 48.]]

 [[32. 92. 56.]
  [52. 74. 12.]
  [63. 58. 81.]]

 [[16. 89. 24.]
  [26. 33. 82.]
  [80. 66. 89.]]]
```

If I understood everything correctly up until now this should be possible with numpy.reshape but I'm not getting it to work. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Simply reshape?

Comment: But as what? I think i didn't understand correctly the reshape function yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to relize what shape the array is. Looking at the one you currently have, it's (5, 1, 9): 5 elements in the top-level dimension, each element is an array of shape (1, 9).

Now you want to have the same number of top-level elements (think rows), but inside arrays of shape (3, 3), so  you need to call:

```
your_array.reshape((5, 3, 3))
```

In the [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) you can find examples of usage and important info on the behavior, e.g. when it would return a view and when a copy.

Comment: That helped a ton thank you. Everything above 2D is sometimes still confusing but I think I got it now :)